# xray subsegments sdk golang

Tags: go, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-xray

I am creating segments and subsegments in golang to send to XRay, but I am getting a lot of problems with it.

FIrst I don't have continuity with the trace map balls.

Second the subsegments don't appear:

third i am asigning the segment to xRay group but it not works
This is my code:

```
func init() {

    xray.Configure(xray.Config{
        ServiceVersion: "1.2.3",
    })
}

func handler(ctx context.Context, event events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    
    ctx2, segment := xray.BeginSegment(ctx, "segment1")
    segment.Origin = "XrayGroup"

    ctx3, subseg1 := xray.BeginSubsegment(ctx2, "sub-segment1")
    xray.AddMetadata(ctx2, "key1", "value1") // add metadata to segment 1
    xray.AddMetadata(ctx3, "key2", "value2") // sub add metadata to segment 2

    logger.Info(ctx, ".....Subsegments......", zap.Any("", segment.Subsegments))

    subseg1.ParentID = segment.ID

    defer subseg1.Close(nil)

    defer segment.Close(nil)

    logger.Info(ctx, ".....Subsegments......", zap.Any("", segment.Subsegments))

    _, segment2 := xray.BeginSegment(ctx2, "segment2")

    logger.Info(ctx, ".....Subsegments......", zap.Any("", segment.Subsegments))

    defer segment2.Close(nil)

    return *u.ResponseAPIGWStringMessage(http.StatusBadRequest, "ya casi funciona"), nil
    //return response, err

}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handler)
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tn8Iq.png)

After all only appear the segment1

If I remove         subseg1.ParentID = segment.ID

appear segment2

but client -> segment2

But not with segment1 parent

that the subsegments appear

Answer (score 0):

XRay data model is tricky, some important criteria:

- Segment is a node in XRay console, Subsegment is not.
- Subsegment has to have an available parent Segment, else it won't appear in xray console
- subsegment can have namespace=remote/aws, then it is inferred to be a Segment in xray console
- In one process, Segment cannot has child Segment, Segment can only has child Subsegment.

That causes some mysterious symptom in using X-Ray SDK.
Please try to onboard [ADOT](https://aws-otel.github.io/docs/getting-started/go-sdk) instead of XRay SDK for go. The opentelemetry API can satisfy your requirement. Make sure using Span.Kind.Server for XRay Segment, Span.Kind.Client or Internal for XRay Subsegment.